# Selecting 'This Month' range by default in bootstrap daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I'm using Bootstrap Daterange Picker, which uses the following range options :

```
ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
      },
```

But when the page loads the selected value is empty.

I want to select the range '**This Month**' by default when the page loads, in bootstrap daterangepicker.

Jsfiddle Url: https://jsfiddle.net/renishar/wnuy6ypc/

Comment: Set the startDate and endDate options to the respective value of `This month`. Call cb function after initialise your datepicker to set the first value => https://jsfiddle.net/wnuy6ypc/6/

Comment: wow, thank you, can u post it as answer.

Comment: also 1 need is there any way to call:  'apply.daterangepicker' event in startup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set the startDate and endDate options to the respective value of This month.

Also call cb function after initialise your datepicker to set the first value

See here : https://jsfiddle.net/wnuy6ypc/6

```
var dat_opt = {
      ...,
      startDate: moment().startOf('month'),
      endDate: moment().endOf('month'),
      ranges: {
        ...
      },
}
```

EDIT : After initialisation add `jQuery('.daterange').trigger("apply.daterangepicker");`

Comment: is there any way to trigger 'apply.daterangepicker' event after initialisation